# Get the raw hex from substrate

Tags: extrinsic, transactions, substrate-node, api

I'm trying to get the raw value of the transaction without using the websocket.
For now I'm using a WebSocket for my application and I am in the process of removing it, I could find everything I wanted on substrate expect the original value in "extrinsics". Is there a way to get it ? My current work is to to try to rebuilt it with the data from the block that I received from substrate but not sure of how this can be done. But even if this can be done, every type of transaction has a different content and that is opening the door for lot of mistakes.

```
{
"block": {
 "header": {
   "parentHash": "0x723d60ec7870e881477ee638aae8b9226e37d0b1c1d0a8b8fbea08d5594e412d",
   "number": "0x1b",
   "stateRoot": "0x7ffe18a6a48979ccf0f41b5ae31bcf14076ba60cf3e006a33856cd0411df9465",
   "extrinsicsRoot": "0x80f5180564d5f5dc1b98e18abbd383dc35f0bc0ec996c517bc07316c431da1a9",
   "digest": {
     "logs": [
       "0x0642414245b5010300000000e7e2cd1000000000f0ce7e95377374a4a1d157034f14d949547bb25acebcc2533a1ef94690203409f596f4167f577ec5971f2718da3005d80258de8008f42833a8bed8b812b45e082d1d9f452808a6df2529e5a8d8a7cb36e581460063576d9f77ced3a91a5e2a06",
       "0x054241424501013e06daff0861a460e3e4433e06d9ea3e1a03c72d4725fa2d8d4cfc995a9b3b3e07e64b9f63200c05b895a69746c63d21ebf319ca525604356a70dede74522881"
     ]
   }
 },
 "extrinsics": [
   "0x280403000b100676d98901",
   "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",
   "0x41028400d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d01b8b84d2b12deb6519799e4a14c0b1c4138bb25f9d60a50ec320967982675eb69f1ea2fa65419ab354d7780c082fad3d41d45b4db43061cc7a73b2d432987b6848501040005070056f14a2288b6ab1668ea4281a830666821431ba62cfbdf6fb432f468ba56116d07005cb2ec22"
 ]
},
"justifications": null
}
```

I would like this value

> 0x41028400d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d01b8b84d2b12deb6519799e4a14c0b1c4138bb25f9d60a50ec320967982675eb69f1ea2fa65419ab354d7780c082fad3d41d45b4db43061cc7a73b2d432987b6848501040005070056f14a2288b6ab1668ea4281a830666821431ba62cfbdf6fb432f468ba56116d07005cb2ec22

The best way would be directly from substrate and if not possible build from what substrate gives me. Is this possible without websocket ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve from taking this approch? `scale-value` crate can be used for dynamicly deserialising scale if you don't want to use the standard per-parachain strong typing routes that subxt gives. (You're asking how to decode a block and get the extrinsics. It's a little tricky because of the sign extras on each signed transaction. I have a go here but don't take it as gospel: https://github.com/gilescope/polkadyn/blob/178b8fe44192e19a0912354fe08a21ef9d2abda6/src/lib.rs#L120  )

Comment: You could do http(s) rather than websocket but if you want to get the data in binary then you'd have to talk libp2p with a node (non-trivial). At the moment hex encoded scale encoded in json is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the endpoint `/blocks/:blockId/extrinsics-raw` of [Sidecar](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar) which returns a block along with its extrinsics as hex strings. This endpoint was added on [v17.3.0](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/releases/tag/v17.3.0) and the response it returns is very similar to what you need :

```
{
  "parentHash": "0x949c61fe1ad22f823efa036d1fc7c7bc6e20462d595ad63e29edbb8ddb88e2ff",
  "number": "0x0111da7e",
  "stateRoot": "0x8aaf3eebc40116ce71a883454623df3a608da3c5cd940800d8ca0c10910959bf",
  "extrinsicRoot": "0xe34596913819f563d0880e2b33ea8f8016d0c8dd62abd0d0383d0f7a938825d8",
  "digest": {
    "logs": [
      {
        "type": "PreRuntime",
        "index": "6",
        "value": [
          "0x42414245",
          "0x035400000031ecdf100000000018e190a2cf7e332a60fe86950752e2b9b9f446bd71628832a2646603f7ee244e65002b815a440e2e625cbb629ad4165c6aa78e76a0dec009eea0b8e0e1f50f0f6d59bc98b2f6f31d7003255cabf900cc811bfb67d9484fb08ee8d2b0d5709b0f"
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "Seal",
        "index": "5",
        "value": [
          "0x42414245",
          "0x2cc27242fbc6904860eb252e32b3fa2feb9f26c6e27a52308b7a11b44230f42e23d84ed628a8cd570e2cba8860ebcbf687af25e564013ff707e2ac6f278b498e"
        ]
      }
    ]
   },
   "extrinsics": [
   "0x280403000b70bc2f808b01",
      "0x86680200043600a104ec3f2410c680ad000000000000cefcd9bf686783c725c83d0ec8164bd1a3d3330deefe2bc4f67e1a74514970429d6f9019be7ce7a33a0c1c2808946fa9a5463febb7b6b701e7d6885d98e62b89ec3f2410c680ad000001000000a8d......",
      "0xad0184009a2960ba755f4f91f2ecbd9ba881baead34353d33eac421d289d925c96738e320148b27c6f9f0dcbab22a035da3a97c4d0f273e0316e1b027a0bb2d6c45a8761688ed14840ba28082a2d1ce7b4520e5895513971791ad1a8137f8f9a072679908a8503290100270101"
      ]
}
```

More details about the endpoint can be found in the [PR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/pull/1334) that implemented it and the [docs](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate-api-sidecar/dist/).